# Nifi ConsumeKafka error while receiving the data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I got an error while using the ConsumeKafka_2_6 1.19.1 processor . Below is the complete error from the NiFi Bulletin board.

08:49:45 UTCERROR7378316d-4765-1fdd-76cd-cbd9fb7ab699
ConsumeKafka_2_6[id=7378316d-4765-1fdd-76cd-cbd9fb7ab699] Exception while processing data from kafka so will close the lease org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumerPool$SimpleConsumerLease@3511a438 due to StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=b1f2cccc-aa9a-4751-9a7c-4ab5eb514555,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1703062164849-3517, container=default, section=445], offset=234005, length=3975],offset=0,name=b1f2cccc-aa9a-4751-9a7c-4ab5eb514555,size=3975] is not known in this session (StandardProcessSession[id=43911398]): org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=b1f2cccc-aa9a-4751-9a7c-4ab5eb514555,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1703062164849-3517, container=default, section=445], offset=234005, length=3975],offset=0,name=b1f2cccc-aa9a-4751-9a7c-4ab5eb514555,size=3975] is not known in this session (StandardProcessSession[id=43911398])

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDCej.png)

I'm using nifi 1.19.1 along with kafka_3.3.2 version, please let me know if any one knows the root cause of this error.